# Calculate destination point

Tags: math

I want to draw a 3d line from one 3d point to another 3d point.

I know the source point, but need to calculate the destination point. I have the angle and the length of the line. The y coordinate (the height) is the same for the source and the destination point.

Thanks

Comment: If you know the y-coordinate is fixed, then this is just a 2-d problem. High school trig. Can you compute the remaining sides of a right triangle, knowing only the length of the hypotenuse, and an angle? Of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic trig, imagine a bunch of triangles along the various planes and solve for the sides/angles you want to know.

If you give us some sample values for what you already know we can show you the maths.

Comment: ok, I have a source point of (0,0,0) and have an angle of 90 degrees and wish the line to be 100 units long.

Comment: angle of 90 degrees between what? or along which plane?

Comment: If you think in 2D space, you might mean that there's an angle of 90 degrees between the line and the x-axis (going counter-clockwise).  If that was the case then the 2nd point would be: (0, 100, 0)

Comment: Is this formula correct: dest_point(x,y,z) = source_point(x,y,z) + direction(x,y,z) * line_length

Comment: Assuming that you are representing direction with a vector of length 1 then that would work.

Comment: the length will not always be 1... it will range between 0 and something like 300. Is there another formula that I can use?

Comment: You had the right idea, you just need to figure out how to calculate your "angle" in the form of a unit vector (length 1) then multiply that by the actual distance and add it to the source point.

Comment: OK, my 'angle' is a bearing... how can I change this to a unit vector?

Comment: @SimonCanning: The unit vector will be (cos(angle), sin(angle)). Guy, you're not going to get this right without learning a little bit of trig; just search for "basic trigonometry" and put in half an hour.

Comment: How about for a 3d unit vector?

Comment: It all depends how you have your angle/bearing specified.  A 3d angle is more than just a simple/single degree measurement.  You have to give us an example of what your data looks like.

Comment: OK, I have a facing angle for my 3d object (in either radians or degrees), a height of 50 (the ship is 50 units high above the landscape.) What other info do you need?